No possible way in VersionedTransactions for Program Interactive Methods to be called within instruction
I found only transaction with SystemProgram are called in version Transactions , and no other way to call contract methods instructions in versiontransaction.
need discussions over this issue

hello, could you provide more info? What are you trying to do and what error have you faced

I am  invoking my contract's method instruction using verstionTransaction , because previously when I was invoking method so it was hitting  me this  error of transaction size
Error: Transaction too large: 1286 > 1232 ,
So now I decided to wrap my transaction instruction inside VersionTransaction but it is not happening as I wish for.

The TX limit isn't increased by switching the versioned transactions. You might need a lookup table

@Jimii I tried batch airdrop using lookup table by making batch instruction and passing the createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction (if spl-token account doesnot exists) and createMintToInstruction , and sesding this instruction in an array form only it supports 10 accounts to mint spl to other accounts
`
messageWithLookupTable =  TransactionMessage({
payerKey
recentBlockhash
instructions: instructions
}).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount.value]);
..remaining sendTransaction and confirmTx
`
Any other way that I can batch more than 10 accounts?

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/batch-airdrop-spl-tokens
