Batch Airdrop Spl Tokens
I was working over batch airdrop script.js I found only I can airdrop spl-tokens only to 10 ATA accounts due to this Error: Transaction too large: 1270 > 1232
Is there any approach that helps me to airdrop more than 10 accounts in a single Tx?

As a simple alternative, you can simply airdrop to fewer accounts and create more transactions.
Otherwise, you can also use address lookup tables to do a bigger airdrop. You need to write the account addresses into the table and then reference it later in a transaction. That might be a bit heavy though, and still limits you to a total of 64 accounts per transaction (including the fee payer, programs, mint, etc).
More information about address lookup tables at https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#address-lookup-tables-lut

You can either check out jito bundles which should allow you to batch together transactions.
But they only work with mainnet-beta and testnet clusters.
Note: that you are also limited to five transaction or fewer when using the bundles
docs: https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles
explorer: https://explorer.jito.wtf/ (only works on mainnet-beta)
Use the code snippet below cautiously as I haven't tested it before. Don't also forget to serialize your transactions to base58 and update the block engine endpoint appropriately
    const tx = ....;
    tx.sign([signer]);

    const encodedTx = bs58.encode(Buffer.from(umi.transactions.serialize(fromWeb3JsTransaction(tx))));

    (await umi.rpc.call("sendBundle", [
        [[encodedTx]],
    ])) as any;

More examples using the Jito client -> https://github.com/jito-labs/jito-ts
You might also want to check how Metaplex does it under the hood with Hydra -> https://developers.metaplex.com/hydra
